# Exposing build date with Vite + React

Tags: reactjs, build, vite

Im trying to log build date for my React+Vite app. All i need is something like this in my index.html:

`<script>console.log(__BUILD_DATE__);</script>`

and `__BUILD_DATE__` replaced with build time string on build

Answer (score 9):

You can try config on file vite.config.ts :

```
define: {
   BUILD_TIMESTAMP: new Date(),
},
```

Answer (score 3):

This didn't work in index.html, but in a component, it worked great:

in vite.config.js

```
define: {
    BUILD_DATE: JSON.stringify(new Date().valueOf()),
  },
```

I made a `<BuildDate />` component which isn't necessary, but hides it all.

```
// BuildDate.tsx
export const BuildDate = () => {
  return <div className="buildDate">Build DATE: {BUILD_DATE}</div>;
};
```

Note: Your IDE will complain if the `BUILD_DATE` constant isn't defined.  Remember, the string will be replaced at build time with the value, so the actual constant is never used in code.

Add it to `vite-env.d.ts` so your IDE is happy.  (thanks for the suggestion @user115014)

```
// vite-env.d.ts

/// <reference types="vite/client" />
declare const BUILD_DATE: string;
```

Comment: Using `declare const BUILD_NUMBER: number` in a `vite-env.d.ts` file should eliminate need to declare and assign to your BUILD_NUMBER const in the component.

Comment: Good point for using `JSON.stringify` as is necessary, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers pretty much already cover it, but I want to add a few more details since it was confusing to me and I didn't find any other Stackoverflow pages on this subject.

First - read the Vite documentation on [define](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#define) and [environment variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode).

Second - if you want to make a constant that you can access in your application, do what the others said above. Put a uniquely named variable in the `define` section of your vite config file:

```
define: {
  BUILD_DATE: JSON.stringify(new Date().toISOString())
}
```

And then in your `vite-env.d.ts` or `env.d.ts` file put this:

```
declare const BUILD_DATE: string;
```

And in your app you can use the `BUILD_DATE` variable, it doesn't need to be imported.

Third - if you prefer to set a custom or dynamic environment variable in your vite config file (rather than in a `.env` file) you can do this:

```
define: {
  'import.meta.env.VITE_BUILD_DATE': JSON.stringify(new Date().toISOString())
}
```

Then in your `vite-env.d.ts` or `env.d.ts` file you can define that value:

```
interface ImportMetaEnv {
  readonly VITE_BUILD_DATE: string;
}
```

And then in your code you can access that environment variable as you normally would in a vite app - `import.meta.env.VITE_BUILD_DATE`.

If you wanted to access an environment variable in your `index.html` file, you can also do this:

```
<div>%VITE_BUILD_DATE%</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the clear writedown! this works as expected. untill you use `yarn build --watch` i think that in this case the config is only read once at script start - and therefore the `new Date()` is only updated at this point.. maybe it is possible to write a very simple plugin that gets called every time... (but iam missing the basics for this..)